# Python lxml: how to get human-readable XPath for XML element?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a short XML document:

```
<tag1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://example.com/2009/namespace">
    <tag2>
        <tag3/>
        <tag3/>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

A short Python program loads this XML file like this:

```
from lxml import etree

f = open( 'myxml.xml' )
tree = etree.parse(f)
MY_NAMESPACE = 'http://example.com/2009/namespace'
xpath = etree.XPath( '/f:tag1/f:tag2/f:tag3', namespaces = { 'f': MY_NAMESPACE } )
# get first element that matches xpath
elem = xpath(tree)[0]
# get xpath for an element 
print tree.getpath(elem)
```

I am expecting to get a meaningful, human-readable xpath with this code, however, instead I get a string like `/*/*/*[1]`.

Any idea what could be causing this and how I can diagnose this issue?

Note: Using Python 2.7.9 and lxml 2.3

Comment: it looks like it's giving you the absolute XPath to access the element, which seems to be the most programmatic sensible way to access it. Though without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to tell you why and if you can get something better.

Comment: @zmo The program itself is very small, however XML document that I used to reproduce the issue is quite long. What do you think is the best way I can post it here for examination?

Comment: `/*/*[1]/*[2]` is what is called a _positional_ XPath expression. But it does not seem to be a complex document. If you find the behaviour of your code puzzling, take away the complexity and try again. And if you want anyone to diagnose the issue, we absolutely need to see the input document - the shortest one possible that stills exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: Managed to reproduce with a tiny XML file! Question updated.

Comment: I wrote a small C program to try this in libxml2 using underlying C call `xmlGetNodePath` and I am observing the same behaviour. Note that if I strip away the namespaces, the xpath generated is `/tag1/tag2/tag3[1]` instead of `/*/*/*[1]`.

Comment: With `getelementpath()`, the result is `{http://example.com/2009/namespace}tag2/{http://example.com/2009/namespace}tag3[1]` (the root element is not included).

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for this @mzjn! Looking at source code, this function is a pure Python tree walk up to root node rather than libxml2 call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `getpath()` (underlying libxml2 call `xmlGetNodePath`) produces positional expression xpath for namespaced documents.
User mzjn in the comments section pointed out that since lxml v3.4.0 a function `getelementpath()` produces a human-readable xpath with fully qualified tag names (using ["Clark notation"](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm)). This function generates xpath by traversing the tree from the node up to the root instead of using libxml2 API call.

Similarly, if lxml v3.4+ is not available one can write a tree traversal function of their own.

Comment: The path produced by `getelementpath()` does not have namespace prefixes; it has fully qualified names (using "Clark notation").

Comment: According to http://lxml.de/index.html#download, the latest version of lxml is 3.4.4. And `getelementpath` was introduced in 3.4.0.